# I am making an array by random number and then want to sorting it without using sort function

Tags: arrays, random

I just started to programming so I'm a beginner.
I'm going to make an array of random number between -1 and 1 and then sort them without using sort function.

```
from random import*
 x = uniform(-1,1)
```

This I did for single random number.

For sorting without using sort function:

```
>>>a = [5, 2, 4, 1]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a) - 1):
       if a[j] > a[j+1]:
           t = a[j]
           a[j] = a[j+1] 
           a[j] = t

print a
```

I don't know how I should find `a[]`, because the first step for generating random number give me a single number, and I want to have an array of this generation.

Comment: Can you tell us what language you are starting to learn. We cannot help until we know what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Is this question only about *generating an array of random numbers*? If it is, this is how you can do it:

```
from random import *
n_numbers = 10
a = [uniform(-1, 1) for x in range(n_numbers)]
```

This is a python-specific trick called *list comprehension* (third line).

You could do the same thing in a *for* loop, appending a new random number to a list. But the way I suggested is probably the easiest in python without additional libraries.

Comment: @epsilonn Then you may mark this answer as accepted, or upvote it and wait for other answers a bit.